# Set my sharepoint list to the contribute permission without breaking the inheritance

Tags: sharepoint-online

I would like to set my sharepoint list to a Contribute permission. So the user can only add, edit or delete records in the list. Is this possible without breaking the inheritance.

I use the modern experience.

Gr. P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to break inheritance then you will need to set the contribute permission at site level.